# Why does the crew get infected from the Vodka in Leviathan

Tags: leviathan

In the 1989 movie [Leviathan](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097737/) the crew finds an old Russian submarine and brings aboard a bottle of Vodka. After drinking the Vodka members of the crew mutate into a sea creature that attacks the rest of the crew.

Isn't their DNA matured by a virus in the bottle? Wouldn't the alcohol in the Vodka act as a disinfectant and kill any viruses, and how did the virus get into the bottle in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If memory serves, the vodka was infected on purpose by the Russians so they could see what happened to the crew. As for disinfecting, I'm no biologist but I believe that viruses can survive under some harsh conditions that would kill most bacteria.

Comment: Just finished watching it. The crew talks about it being put into the Vodka in the kitchen after one of them dies. I find this part of the story a little weak, cause they seem to assume that this was done on purpose. Other then the submarine being listed as still in active duty. There are no other clues to the Russian's motivations. It's been twenty years now. I guess I shouldn't hold my breath for a sequel.